# Добавление и удаление методов

Tags: c#

Всем привет!
Вопрос по аоп. Есть разные инструменты для изменения и добавления cil. Например, mono.cecil. Но то, что я нашел позволяет лишь изменять/добавлять il в теле уже существующих методов. Можно ли с помощью подобных инструментов добавить новые или удалить существующие методы из сборки?

Comment: Если оперируете методами, то почему не декомпилировать сборку и вписать этот метод на C#?

Comment: _Удалить_ - что должно происходить в случае, если далее по коду эти методы будут вызываться? _Добавить_ - вероятно, подойдут [Деревья выражений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/).

Comment: @JaponDemon, я могу декомпилировать и вписать с помощью ildasm/ilasm, но вручную. А надо программно. И желательно без существенной потери скорости

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, при вызове удаленного метода должна быть ошибка. Так задумано пока. В идеале в общем-то его подмена. Деревья смотрел, но допустим, я получил делегат через Compile(), как мне его сохранить в сборку?

Comment: @JaponDemon, хотя не, скорость значения, думаю, не имеет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде нашел ответ на свой вопрос: в том же Mono.Cecil у TypeDefinition.Methods можно вызвать Add/Remove, чего нет в Reflection.

PS: Пытался сделать с помощью Expression или Reflection, но не придумал, как сохранять видоизмененную сборку. Expression умеет компилировать новые методы, а Reflection менять местами старые, но все только в рантайме